# Show back button on video player android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

my question is i want to show back button while i play video. at this time when i play my video its only showing me play button and revers and forward buttons. but i need to show back button on the top left corner. so i f press back button app should take me to back screen.please i am new in android development.thanks in advance. i have added my code also.

```
public class ClipActivity extends Activity {

    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.clip);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        try {

            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setEnabled(true);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

            Intent it = getIntent();
            if (it != null) {

                Bundle params = it.getExtras();

                if (params != null) {
                    url = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("clip");
                }
            }

            Log.i("feed", "url = " + url);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
            videoView.start();
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: i solve the issue by adding image button with "prev btn style" in my xml file and then on the main activity i add imagebutton listner with finish(). thanks